# rmarkdown render_site: how to set dynamic texts in navbar

Tags: html, r, render, r-markdown

In rmarkdown, it is possible to create a navbar for the site web, with the yaml file. The official documentation is [here](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/rmarkdown_websites.html#site_navigation).

I would like to know if it is possible to add dynamic texts and link in the navbar.

For example:

```
name: "my-website"
navbar:
  title: "My Website"
  type: inverse
  left:
    - text: "`r txt1`"
      icon: fa-home
      href: index.html
```

Then in the rmd file, I can specify

```
txt1= "Home"
```

Before using `render_site` function.